# Blender`s assign material to face analog in Godot

Tags: shaders, godot

I am very new to Godot. I am using version 3.4 stable on Windows 10.

I made a building in Blender and I wanted to make interior mapping instead of poor 2d windows textures. I found a material for that, and just assigned it to windows faces.

Unfortunately that model failed to be imported as .escn, so I decided to import it with one whole material, and then do the same last steps in Godot. I am going to use [this shader](https://godotengine.org/asset-library/asset/390) for that.

I imported it, created new `ShaderMaterial`, then `VisualShader` and setup as you can see in screenshot.

What is next? How do I select windows faces and set to them interior mapping shader? Is that possible in Godot at all?

[image]

Mesh:

[image]

---

@Theraot solution is working:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are editing the `Mesh` resource, you should see in the Inspector Panel a series of properties named "Surface 1", "Surface 2" and so on. Each one has a material assigned. There you can replace the material with your new `ShaderMaterial` (alternatively you could edit the materials that were imported along with the model).

Similarly, if you are editing a `MeshIntance`, you should se a series of material properties which are overrides for the materials of the `Mesh` resource, and you can also se the `ShaderMaterial`.

If you don't see multiple surfaces/materials, then your model got a single surface. And no, Godot does not have the means to divide surfaces.

---

Addendum post edit: Yep, that is a signle material in your `MeshInstance`. Multiple look like this:

[image: MeshInstance with multiple materials]

And in the `Mesh` they look like this:

[image: Mesh with multiple surfaces]

You can open the `Mesh` resource from the `MeshInstance` by clicking on its Mesh property, it should be an `ArrayMesh`.

---

As you have certainly found out, you are not going going to get complex Blender materials on Godot. Both parts have a bit of blame here, because Blender materials are not standard, and only the simplest can be encoded in standard formats. If you are using a Godot exporter addon in Blender, it might try its best to translate the materials, but some just cannot be recreated, and that part has to do with Godot limitations.

Thus, my advice is to set simple materials for the different surfaces you need. And then if you need more complex materials, override them in Godot with materials that work on engine.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Okay, so because I don't have multiple materials, what is the solution? Assign new materials in Blender, but just make them like empty? And then I will see them in that window in Godot?

Comment: @АртурКлочко They don't have to be empty, just simple enough. PBR materials should import fine. In fact, I would recommend exporting and importing gltf (v2). Anything that can be encoded in gltf both Godot and Blender will agree on.

Comment: Ok, I will test it today, but it is sad, that I can't handle model`s geometry as in Blender or another editor. Hope there is a Godot addon or plugin for this

Comment: @АртурКлочко It should be possible as an addon. However, I believe the Godot core developers don't want to replicate something you can do in other free software. Instead what they are working on - in communication with the Blender foundation - is better integration with Blender, for Godot 4.0 or 4.1. Part of this effort is the current rework of the animation system. We should get to the point where you will be able to save a .blend file in a Godot project folder, and Godot will notice it and (re)import it, with minimum breakage, and reapplying any edits done on the Godot side.

Comment: Yeah I've heard about 4.0 version, especially for new Vulcan API, but when it all will be.. I think I rather move to Unreal Engine 5

Comment: @АртурКлочко Godot 4.0 is in pre-alpha stage. There are some official builds [here](https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/godotengine/testing/4.0/), and some unofficial not-optimized builds [here](https://hugo.pro/projects/godot-builds/). You can try it. It is nowhere as heavy as Unreal. It is usable, but by no means stable. There are still a handful of blocking bugs at the time of writing, including crashes, you can see [here](https://github.com/orgs/godotengine/projects/16). We should have an alpha once those are resolved. Yes, it keeps being delayed. I'm not telling you to wait. Godot 3.x works.

Comment: Thanks for help, now it works, although shader I mentioned has error in code, but I better create another question.

Comment: Also it seems that I found a bug, perhaps: when I created material for #1 slot, I just dragged it two #2 slot, and obviously it was copied as a link, so when I change material (including) the VisualShader in first slot, the second will also be changed. But when I pressing "make unique" for material or for shader, they are still linked with the original one, so I need to delete duplicate and create it separately

Comment: @АртурКлочко I think you duplicated the material resulting in another material with the same shader. That is, the shader was shared between the two materials. Which can be useful, if you can make the materials only differ in shader parameters (uniforms) Godot does not have to compile a shader for each one.

Comment: Shader itself also has "make unique" in dropbox when you press it, but it does not make any sense. However

Comment: @АртурКлочко Perhaps some way to duplicate them together makes sense. It could ask you if you want to make a deep copy. Or it could be another option aside from make unique. Or that could be the default. You can write a proposal at https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals or report a bug at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues